# How to get values of cells of selected row in datagrid in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wpfdatagrid

Am trying to get values from the cells in a selected row in a datagrid but in vain. I have been able to do this easily in datagridview in windows forms but the same is not working in wpf datagrid. The code I have tried so far is below:

```
    `If Me.mileGrd.Items.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.mileGrd.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("check me")
            Dim cnum As String = Me.mileGrd.SelectedItems(0).Cells("Car No").Value
            'do more stuff here
        End If
    End If`
```

`mileGrd` is the datagrid.
When I run the program, I get an error message that `Public member 'Cells' on type 'DataRowView' not found` . What could I cahnge to enable me read values of the cells from selected row in datagrid with the column header as parameter like `Car No` in this case? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cnum = From row in mileGrd.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
Select row.Cells("Car No").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get errors when I use that code. Are you sure it works? Maybe explain abit. First I see `DataGridViewRow` and yet am using `DataGrid`